# Front Driver-side window stopped working

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, power-windows, blazer

**Vehicle**: 2000 Chevy Blazer 4WD

**Issue**: Front Driver-Size window button is no longer working.

**Other Details**:
I checked all other buttons and electrical related things and they all appear to be working. If I turn the window lock on, then hold the front driver-side window button down it'll start making a clicking noise (up nor any other buttons cause this to occur).

**Question**: Would this be a wiring issue or the regulator? If it's a wiring issue how would I go about fixing it? Are you able to just go to a parts store and get replacements or would I have to rewire something?

Answer (score 1):

It will either be a problem with the switch or with the regulator (motor). Usually if it's the motor, it will *overheat* and stop working (partially roll down and stop), then after a while it will work again and move the window another inch or two. If it's the switch, it could partially work or not at all. It is highly unlikely it would be the wiring, as it rarely if ever goes bad (unless it's messed with or the vehicle gets in an accident and the wiring is disturbed for some reason). It could *possibly* be an issue where both the switch and the motor are bad, but that is highly unlikely.

Comment: For this particular case, the clicking sound tells me that the electrical connection is fine, so probably the window regulator is kaput.